# Ubuntu does not recognize windows and I'd like to delete windows. NOT dual-boot

Tags: boot

I'm setting up ubuntu on an old laptop that has nothing on it. I want to get rid of windows and set up ubuntu 20.

Everything works fine I'm booting from USB but once I get to the installation screen, it does NOT detect an operating system.

This is the choice I WANT:

[image: example]

However, I do not do not get that "erase windows" option. Instead it tells me it does not detect an operating system. Is this going to result in dual boot? Or will the option "delete everything..." actually delete windows?

Comment: Welcome, just use gparted to format the disk.

Comment: That means you are probably not using UEFI to boot the live session.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. In first sentence you say you have an old laptop with **nothing** on it. In the next sentence you say you want to get rid of Windows. . .duh?

Comment: I meant nothing of importance. Windows was still installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to, then choose the "delete everything" option. Otherwise, choose something else, click on every partition that shows up, and press the delete button. Then you will have all free space. Click on the space and simply click next. No need for further partitioning , it will do all by itself.

Comment: thanks this worked!